# ActionLink from Razor View Engine targeting aspx area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink, razorengine

I'm doing one area in MVC5 application that contains reporting in aspx.

I can access to that page thanks to this URL:

```
http://localhost:28790/Areas/Reporting/Reporting.aspx
```

But now How Can i made this link in my razor view, in MVC-like (with action link for instance) ?

I already tried

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reporting", "Index", "Reporting", new { area = "Reporting" }, null)
```

But the link is in error : I get Reporting on the screen...

Here is the registration of the area:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Reporting_default",
                "Reporting/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                "~/Reporting.aspx"
            );
        }
```

I've made nothing else in order to configure routing

Thanks to help me

Answer (score 0):

I had a look round and I'm not sure there's an in built way to do this but you could utilise method here `Url.Action()` which may help.

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Index", "Reporting", new { area = "Reporting" }) + ".aspx")">Reporting</a>
```

`Url.Action` will generate the link `/Areas/Reporting/Reporting` and then you're simply adding `.aspx` to the end of the `href`.

Comment: nice but no.. it gives me <a href=".aspx">Reporting</a> Maybe he don't want to make the link because he knows this is not possible...

Comment: did you edit anything else than me? I just edited the route of the area

Comment: The url is http://localhost:28790/Areas/Reporting/Reporting.aspx, normally woth routing, it must run for http://localhost:28790/Reporting/Reporting.aspx but not... why?